# How to log fields having @JsonIgnore annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, aspectj, slf4j, java-17

I am using `Spring Boot 2.7.3` with `Java 17` & `Gradle`. I need to log every DB operations in a log file. Everything is working fine except one condition. When I am using `@JsonIgnore` in my UI Class, these particular fields are not logged. Other fields are properly logged. How to deal with it ?

My Aspect Class:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.mycomp.erp.service..*(..))")
    public void requestPointcut() {}

    @Before("requestPointcut()")
    public void requestLogger(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        final Object[] inputArguments = joinPoint.getArgs();

        final String logMessage = "Operation : " + methodName +
                " With Input Parameters : " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputArguments);

        logger.info(logMessage);
    }
}
```

My UI Record Class:

```java
public record LeaveApplUx(
    @JsonIgnore String employeeCode,
    @JsonIgnore int applicationNumber,
    LocalDate startDate,
    LocalDate endDate,
    String leaveType) {
    public LeaveApplUx(

    @Size(min = 4, max = 5, message = "Employee Code Must Be Within 4 To 5 Character Long Or Blank")
    @JsonProperty("employeeCode") String employeeCode,

    @Range(min = 0, max = 9999, message = "Application Number Must Be Within 9999 Or Zero")
    @JsonProperty("applicationNumber") int applicationNumber,

    @NotNull(message = "Start Date Empty")
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @JsonProperty("startDate") LocalDate startDate,

    @NotNull(message = "End Date Empty")
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @JsonProperty("endDate") LocalDate endDate,

    @Size(min = 2, max = 2, message = "Leave Type Mis-Match")
    @JsonProperty("leaveType") String leaveType) {

        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
        this.applicationNumber = applicationNumber;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.leaveType = leaveType;

    }
}
```

My Request through Postman:

```
DELETE
http://localhost:8080/hr/leave/application/delete
```

```json
{
    "employeeCode": "E001",
    "applicationNumber": "1",
    "startDate": "01-04-2022",
    "endDate": "05-04-2022",
    "leaveType": "CL"
}
```

My Log File Output:

```
2022-08-30 14:32:53,688 INFO  :  Operation : deleteLeaveApplication With Input Parameters : ["N","N",{"startDate":"01-04-2022","endDate":"05-04-2022","leaveType":"CL"}]
```

The Employee Code & Application Number is not logged.

Comment: The answer will be either (1) don't use the class that contains `@JsonIgnore` for logging or (2) use a different serialization (e.g. use `toString()` in stead of JSON in your logs).

Comment: I have to use this Record Class, because my selection query is this.

POST
http://localhost:8080/hr/leave/application
{
    "startDate": "01-04-2022",
    "endDate": "05-04-2022",
    "leaveType": "CL"
}

Answer (score 3):

The annotation [`@JsonIgnore`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) causes that Jackson's ObjectMapper ignores such fields on serialization. This is the defined behavior.

> Marker annotation that indicates that the logical property that the accessor (field, getter/setter method or Creator parameter [of [JsonCreator](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html)-annotated constructor or factory method]) is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality.

You have two options: Log as an array or configure ObjectMapper for the logging.

---

**Solution #1: Log as an array**

You have *all* the parameters available in the `Object[] inputArguments` array that can be logged directly. I also recommend using the proper logging features:

```
logger.info("Operation: {} with input parameters: {}", 
        methodName, inputArguments);
```

---

**Solution #2: Configure a specific `ObjectMapper`**

For this particular case, you can configure the `ObjectMapper` to ignore the annotations by setting [`MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#USE_ANNOTATIONS) to `false`.

> Feature that determines whether annotation introspection is used for configuration; if enabled, configured AnnotationIntrospector will be used: if disabled, no annotations are considered.

Based on the Jackson version:

- Jackson before 2.13:

  ```
  ObjectMapper ignoringObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper() 
      .configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false);
  ```
- Jackson 2.13 and higher:

  ```
  ObjectMapper ignoringObjectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
          .configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)
          .build();
  ```

... and log it:

```
logger.info("Operation: {} with input parameters: {}", 
        methodName, ignoringObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputArguments));
```

Comment: Thakns for the answer. But

new ObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, false)

shows that is deprecated in Java 17

Comment: @Deep It is not relevant to Java 17. As of Jackson 2.13, the method `new ObjectMapper().configure(...)` is deprecated, and `JsonMapper.builder().configure(...).build()` should be used instead. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice solution, but unfortunately I am using java.time.LocalDate which is not supported by jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException is thrown.

Comment: Well, it is out of the scope of this question. I believe further readers can learn out how to log the JSON request regardless of the `@JsonIgnore`. For the `LocalDate` issue, I recommend asking a question to find the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
Just replace

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputArguments)
```

with this

```
Arrays.toString(inputArguments)
```